# query has no destination for result data TRIGGER

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of BookingIDs where BookingID equals the new insert BookingID. Lets say, there's 5 seat bookings under the same `BookingID`. I want to find if this number [5] exceeds the number of seats ordered in `flightbooking`; if so, then fail. This information can be found in the `NumSeat` column in `FlightBooking`.

However, I am receiving a error: "query has no destination for result data". I suspect my `RETURN NEW;` is incorrect, but I do not know why. If anyone can see any issues with my code I would appreciate it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Ins_Passenger
BEFORE INSERT ON SeatBooking
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_SeatBooking();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_SeatBooking()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    SELECT fb.BookingID, fb.NumSeats
    FROM FlightBooking AS fb
    INNER JOIN SeatBooking AS sb ON fb.BookingID = NEW.BookingID
    INNER JOIN Passenger AS p ON p.PassengerID = NEW.PassengerID;

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(BookingID) FROM SeatBooking WHERE fb.BookingID = NEW.BookingID) > fb.NumSeats)
    THEN ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

INSERT INTO SeatBooking VALUES(10005, 40015, 29);
```

10005 - BookingID

40015 - PassengerID

29 - seat number on plane (ignore)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare variables and use them in an `INTO` clause of the first `SELECT` statement. These variables will receive the query result.

Then you can use the variables in the second SQL statement.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) for details.

Comment: How can I reference new variables being inserted? To elaborate, how would I put INSERT INTO SeatBooking VALUES(1, 2, 3) into declared variables (i.e. DECLARE BookID INTEGER = 1)?

Comment: `INSERT` (without `RETURNING`) has no result. Only SQL statements that have a result need an `INTO` clause with variables that receive the result of the statement.